# How to set the pressed state for ListView in flutter like iOS？

Tags: flutter

// in iOS，When a cell is selected, the background is gray

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

[image]

How to achieve this effect in flutter's listView？

I try to set the background color of the pressed state in the TextButton, but this way displays the gray background for too short a time, and the effect is basically invisible

Comment: Hi, are you asking for Ripple effect when pressing any view?

Comment: No, I want to remove the water ripple effect, and then make the background color gray when the button is pressed and keep it for a certain time. Now, after I set the background color when I press, I can only show this time in a flash. If I click faster, I can't even see the graying effect of the background, so I think I can only achieve this effect through delay

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could explain the expected behavior a bit more in detail. To change the color, you could use a ListTile and change the color upon `onTap`.

However, if I see this correctly, you open some other page when tapping the tile. So you would have to use an animation or delay the forwarding in order to see something

```dart
ListTile(
  leading: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    tileColor: _color,
    onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _color = Colors.grey;
            });
          },
    child: Container(
      width: 48,
      height: 48,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: const CircleAvatar(),
    ),
  ),
  title: const Text('title'),
  dense: false,
)
```

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the gray background for a period of time (for example, 100 milliseconds) before opening another page, so that I can see the effect of pressing an item when I click it (that is, the gray background) before the page jumps, so that users can perceive that an item is pressed. If you simply set the color in ontap () {}, the effect will be instantaneous, and the user will not be able to perceive the pressed state. Sorry, I don't know if I have described it clearly. So I can only achieve this effect through delay or animation

Comment: you could use for example `Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {/*call next widget*/;
});` or `Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {/*call next widget*/;});`

Comment: Or if you use a slow animation, this would do the same trick